# Add specific time from txt file with python schedule library

Tags: python, python-schedule

How can I add times from the text file to the schedule library?

The code snippet below works.

My aim:
Running a function at different time intervals.
But this time interval and the number of times the function runs may vary.

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    
    #not work
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')
    with open("data/timedata.txt", "r") as file3:  
        timedatas = file3.read()
        timedatas = timedatas.split("\n")
        timedatas = list(filter(None, timedatas))
        for timedata in timedatas:
            
            schedule.every().day.at(timedata).do(send_message)
            
            while True:
                await schedule.run_pending()
                await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def send_message():
  print("Work!")
```

timedate.txt

```
12:55
12:57
```

Comment: maybe put the `while` loop outside the `for` loop